# alternative for net use in Linux

Tags: linux, file-transfer, net-use

I am currently working on file transferring system from one server to another one in Linux. I'm still a novice coder and new with Linux. I found that in Window we can actually use net use to connect a server to another server something like:

```
net use destination_server/user:username password
```

Is there a way, we can apply the same concept in linux? 
Would really appreciate the help, Thanks.

Comment: I think this is what you need:
https://linuxize.com/post/how-to-mount-cifs-windows-share-on-linux/
your question is better suited for serverfault...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use ssh but remote server should have ssh server installed.

example command :

```
ssh username@destination_server
```

Other alternatives :

- sftp : You may transfer files but it won't provide direct shell access to remote server meaning you can not use all commands available in that server.
- scp : one line command to transfer files and folders.

Comment: Note that these commands do not involve file system; mount(1) and other variants like sshfs(1) do instead, and are nearer to the semantics (net use) the OP shows.